# MySQL: Creating foreign key between table with primary key and table with no unique columns

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm having trouble figuring this out.

I have two tables, one is quite large with unique values in the column - 'column1'. I want to connect this to a smaller table, with just two columns, one column connected to 'column1' and the other column - 'column2' with null and duplicated values.

The problem is, in 'column1' in the second, smaller table, there will be multiple occurrences of the same values so I cannot make either column in the smaller table a primary key or a unique key in order to connect it with the bigger table via a foreign key.

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the whole point of fks: in the child table you msy have several records with the same value.

Comment: What does "connect this" mean? Use clear technical terms/statements. A FK says subrow values must appear elsewhere as a PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL. Is that what you have? If not, you don't want/have a FK. What condition do you have? Why do you want to tell the DBMS about it? An example would help.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible solutions:

- you can create the primary key using both `column1` and `column2`. You can duplicate one of the two values, as long as the couple doesn't repeat inside the table;
- you can add a third column in your second table (the legendary `id` field), an auto-incremental numeric value, and set it as PK. This way you can duplicate as much as you want, since the `id` will always be different.

Drawbacks:

- the first case is more "theoretically correct", it's what textbooks suggest you to do, but the composed PK might be of heavy computation, depending on the type of the two columns (comparing strings is different than comparing integers)
- the second case is easier to compute (only one value, and numeric), but allows duplicates of couples, which might not be what you want.

Your choice.

**EDIT**

The `null` values might give you some problems, so I would probably go with the numeric, auto-incremental `id` column. I'll keep the answer with both options for future reference.

Comment: The question is not clear enough to know what situation the asker has. They mention FKs but they explicitly say they don't have a case of a FK, and they don't describe things clearly enough to know what constraints are appropriate.

Comment: @philipxy I think the question was clear enough (not the clearest way, I'll give you that), but the title of the question explicitly mentions the necessity of creating a FK, stating that the problem is that one of the table doesn't have a single field to use as PK.